# Trying to open a page after submit in a form

Tags: html, forms, prestashop

I'm trying to add a confirmation page after a submit on a form but i can't figure out why it doesnt work.

I'm working on Prestashop and my action look like that :

`<form action="{$urls.pages.contact}" method="post" {if $contact.allow_file_upload}enctype="multipart/form-data"{/if}>`

i tried differents things like `target="_blank"` or `action="website.com & {$urls.pages.contact}"`

Comment: Edit: i dont really understand what the action does. It look a lot like JSX but i dont know what it is calling or referring to. Explaining it to me might help a lot

Answer (score 0):

The "action" tag of a form value is the URL where the values of post request are sent. It means that you should have a controller+method which must intercept and process those values at this address (URL, route, call it as you want).
Its not mandatory to do it this way since you can send your data with Ajax, but it's not what you want.

A proper way to do what you want is to set the "action" as a route which refers to a controller::method which process your Post data, then redirect to a page with the `Tools::redirect()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot i understand the problem way better now :)